# Using components in Paragraph with ellipsis property Ant UI

Tags: reactjs, antd

Adding something else to `Paragraph` component except string cause error but ellipsis property seems to work fine: `[antd: Typography] ellipsis should use string as children only`. So is there any way to avoid this error and  use components (at least icons) or tags in Paragraph with ellipsis property?